# Where to Fork Recent Posts Widget?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a custom recent posts widget by forking the default WordPress widget. I understand you shouldn;t hack core code, but rather fork the original widget and then register it in the functions file.

The only thing is, I don't know where to fork. I've found the default widget and I know that I'd register the widget in my theme's functions.php file, I just don't know where to save the code I'm forking. For example, do I save it as a plugin in the plugins folder, etc.?

Here's the default WordPress code:

```
/**
 * Recent_Posts widget class
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 */
class WP_Widget_Recent_Posts extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget_recent_entries', 'description' => __( "Your site&#8217;s most recent Posts.") );
        parent::__construct('recent-posts', __('Recent Posts'), $widget_ops);
        $this->alt_option_name = 'widget_recent_entries';

        add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
        add_action( 'deleted_post', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
        add_action( 'switch_theme', array($this, 'flush_widget_cache') );
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        $cache = array();
        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache = wp_cache_get( 'widget_recent_posts', 'widget' );
        }

        if ( ! is_array( $cache ) ) {
            $cache = array();
        }

        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }

        if ( isset( $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] ) ) {
            echo $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ];
            return;
        }

        ob_start();
        extract($args);

        $title = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Recent Posts' );

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/default-widgets.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

        $number = ( ! empty( $instance['number'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        if ( ! $number )
            $number = 5;
        $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? $instance['show_date'] : false;

        /**
         * Filter the arguments for the Recent Posts widget.
         *
         * @since 3.4.0
         *
         * @see WP_Query::get_posts()
         *
         * @param array $args An array of arguments used to retrieve the recent posts.
         */
        $r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array(
            'posts_per_page'      => $number,
            'no_found_rows'       => true,
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
        ) ) );

        if ($r->have_posts()) :
?>
        <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
        <?php if ( $title ) echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>
        <ul>
        <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
            <?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
                <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php echo $after_widget; ?>
<?php
        // Reset the global $the_post as this query will have stomped on it
        wp_reset_postdata();

        endif;

        if ( ! $this->is_preview() ) {
            $cache[ $args['widget_id'] ] = ob_get_flush();
            wp_cache_set( 'widget_recent_posts', $cache, 'widget' );
        } else {
            ob_end_flush();
        }
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['number'] = (int) $new_instance['number'];
        $instance['show_date'] = isset( $new_instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $new_instance['show_date'] : false;
        $this->flush_widget_cache();

        $alloptions = wp_cache_get( 'alloptions', 'options' );
        if ( isset($alloptions['widget_recent_entries']) )
            delete_option('widget_recent_entries');

        return $instance;
    }

    function flush_widget_cache() {
        wp_cache_delete('widget_recent_posts', 'widget');
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $title     = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        $number    = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $instance['show_date'] : false;
?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:' ); ?></label>
        <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" /></p>

        <p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked( $show_date ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_date' ); ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Display post date?' ); ?></label></p>
<?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder in Plugins and save it in there.

You don't have to create a new folder, but I would advise it just to keep the project clean.

More info here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin